# IE8 and quirks mode

Tags: html, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-8

Does IE8 run in quirks mode like IE6/7?

I have a webpage that has some truly bizarre code. The content is centered with padding and negative margins.

It works correctly in IE6/7 and other browsers but in IE8 the content area is half as wide and not centered (flag for quirks mode).

The source code has three blank lines before the DOCTYPE. I know that will throw IE6 into quirks mode. Will it also affect IE8?

I don't have access to the source so I cannot remove those lines to test it.

Comment: Save in your computer and edit the source. See if striping those blank lines works. Quirks mode should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: When you're at the page you're unsure about, just stick the following in the browser window- javascript:alert(document.compatMode); and that should tell you the current mode.

Comment: s/browser window/broswer address bar

Comment: @Emily, if you are trying to quickly fix the problem - use the Compatibility Mode of IE8. To permanently fix it - you need to modify the CSS. When using minimum-width property, you need to specify width as well under IE8. You need to add just one line of code and the page will look fine in IE8:

File: structures.css, line 13:

width: 1000px;

Comment: this solved my quirks mode problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294301/dreamweaver-causing-quirks-mode-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running a few quick tests that can be found [here](http://alastairc.ac/testing/IE_Doctypes/) seem to indicate that blank lines shouldn't throw IE8 into Quirks Mode (which is different to Compatability Mode that everyone seems to be confusing it with).

I wrote a breakdown on how incredibly confusing the different modes of IE8/7 [here](http://www.hallofbrightcarvings.com/exploring-the-many-faces-of-ie8/) and I didn't even include Quirks Mode in the breakdown. A detailed description of Quirks mode can be found [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) (not for the original question, but others might find it interesting.)

Comment: Ah...their doctype is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
According to your chart, that will throw IE8 into quirks mode.

Comment: Heads-up: Link #2 (incredibly confusing different modes of IE8/7) is no longer valid.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the doctype to HTML 5 should fix some problems. I had an issue with min-width in IE8 using Strict doctype.

So changed this:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

To this: <!DOCTYPE html>

See here: http://davidnaylor.org/blog/2008/09/ie8-and-max-width.html

Answer (score 3):

Today, I changed our DOCTYPE from XHTML v1.0 (Strict) to HTML5.  I read somewhere that even though the IE's don't recognize the DOCTYPE yet, they will render the page in standards-compliant mode.

When I checked in IE8, the whole page looked whack (we have quite a bit of CSS and other styling).  It took a while before I realized that there wasn't anything "wrong" with the CSS, or even IE8 for that matter.  However, it WAS rendering in quirks mode.

Inadvertently, I found the answer in the question posted here, specifically this comment: "The source code has three blank lines before the DOCTYPE. I know that will throw IE6 into quirks mode. Will it also affect IE8?"

I don't know about blank lines, but when I made the change, I had used a javascript comment to "hang on to" my old DOCTYPE statement (which was ABOVE the new HTML5 DOCTYPE).  Once I removed those lines (which may have included a blank line or two), my sweating stopped and IE8 rendered in standards-compliant mode.

Comment: You've just saved me many many hours of work hacking; razor placed @using System.Web.Optimization above the Doctype and low and behold, it knocked all the styles out in IE8. I moved it one line below and it's all sorted! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Internet Explorer's quirks mode is IE5.5. IE6/7/8 switch back to 5.5 when quirks mode is present. So since it was working fine in IE6/7 it's not the quirks mode. There's a "Compatibility View" button in IE8 to address this issue. It's not a good solution to me though. You'll have to check your CSS code.

Comment: But shouldn't IE6/7 be in quirks mode too since the blank lines are before the DOCTYPE? It looks fine in compatibility mode. It was developed in IE6 and I am thinking they somehow compensated for the quirks mode which is now throwing IE8 for a loop since it is trying to follow the standards (or some of them).

Comment: @Emily, no it won't put IE8 into quirks mode. You can either change the code so that it renders correctly in IE8 or use one of its compatibility modes. It has 6 modes, and since your site was working fine under 6/7 you can add the following <meta> tag:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />

to force IE8 to use the standard IE7 directives when in standards mode. Quirks mode will be 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 has a compatibility mode which should treat the page the way IE7 would.  Have you tried viewing the page in compatibility mode?

Comment: The page looks fine in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a link to the page or some of the HTML itself?  You could try adding the meta tag to force compatibility mode?

http://www.ditii.com/2008/08/28/ie8-standards-mode-and-ie7-compatibility-mode/

or for more info:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx