# Website will not work / view in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, dreamweaver, quirks-mode

I'm having problems with [my website](http://www.jamesabbottphotography.co.uk) in all versions of Internet Explorer - it just doesn't work in this browser, but works perfectly in all others.

My site is made using my own templates in Dreamweaver and I found an explanation on this site at this link: [Dreamweaver causing Quirks Mode in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294301/dreamweaver-causing-quirks-mode-in-internet-explorer)

Unfortunately, the advice has no effect and the site will still won't view correctly. I've even created a test html page using the code from my index page, minus all the template coding but it still won't work in IE. I just can work out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would use [w3.validator](http://validator.w3.org) and make sure your html is correct.

I would assume what needs to be fixed to get it to work in IE is in here:

```
    <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<div id="copyright"> &copy; 2012 James Abbott. All rights reserved</div>

<!--[if IE]></div><![endif]>
<!--[if !IE]></div><![endif]>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></html>
```

Seems like you have some things to correct there ;) For instance, the if tags are not closed properly and seem to leave out `</body>` when viewed in IE