# Wrong css after submit with error result IE8

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer-8, submit

When I try to submit a login with the wrong credentials, the page loading with wrong css styles. I check in a index.php if the user has an active account, when not, I include the login.php page. When I delete the php at the top, I got no error and the page is in the correct css. So, always when there is a error, the page looks complete different as designed. Maybe the browser dont load the css? or the complete css?

```
<?php
  // show negative messages
  if ($account->errors) {
      foreach ($account->errors as $error) {
          echo $error;
      }
  }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- INITIALISE -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sign in</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- STYLESHEETS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" >

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-wrapper text-center">
      <hr>
      <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="index.php" name="loginform" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">log in.</h2>
        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" name="posted_username" placeholder="User">
        <input type="password" class="input-block-level" name="posted_password" placeholder="Pass">
        <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger" type="submit" name="login">Log in</button>
      </form>
    </div> <!-- /form-wrapper -->

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but it might be because you're printing out the errors before the `html` tag, so the browser is getting upset by the incorrect format of the page and just not loading the css. Perhaps try putting the php inside the `body` tag?

Comment: Did you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245095/ie8-and-quirks-mode ? Any characters before the doctype will put IE8 in "quirks mode".

Comment: is not working. Im wondering, chrome & firefox has no problems with it.

Comment: @ziggyyy Just put your PHP codes under `<body>` try it again and theoretically, it should work. You can work from there after.

Comment: thanks, now, I know what the quirks mode is...

Comment: @ziggyyy IE is "quirky" that way ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dumping your error messages into the page BEFORE the opening `<!DOCTYPE>`/`<html>` tags, which is NOT permitted. That's probably triggering IE to render the page in Quirks mode, which basically changes the entire CSS rendering system to oldschool IE6-style garbage.

Move your error messages to a more suitable location inside the `<body>` area and you'll probably find the css magically starts working better.

Answer (score 1):

This was said in a comment, but I second the opinion. You are not outputting valid html with the code you submitted.

Move the  code inside of the body tag, probably inside of your main div tag.